# get pidof varnish in Ubuntu

Tags: varnish, ubuntu-server

For keepalived I wan't to check if Varnish is running with `pidof varnish` however this does not output anything when I type it in the terminal.

I wan't to set it up als alternative to NGINX as shown in the following snippet:

```
vrrp_script chk_nginx {
    script "pidof nginx"
    interval 2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command is:

```
pidof varnishd
```